# How to integrate the opencv to webots environment in windows?

Tags: c++, opencv, simulation, webots

I want to use opencv for a project for robot simulation. But I am having trouble with using it inside webots. I can't include it. I have the opencv version 4.30 and I changed my makefile to use the opencv but It doesn't work. Can You guys help me how can I add opencv to webots?

Comment: Maybe provide the steps you took, e.g. the Makefile

Comment: Error snippet also you need to share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some documentation about how to use external library with Webots controllers:
https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/using-webots-makefiles?tab-language=ros#adding-an-external-library-ccp

You can also find an example of integration of OpenCV (not version 4.30 but you can for sure take inspiration) in a Webots controller here:
https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots/blob/f6886726c320b86d8ab07cab4d849ca82ca791af/projects/samples/howto/vision/controllers/vision/

Comment: In case of OpenCV, you should probably use [this version](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-i686-opencv?repo=mingw32) that comes with [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org) which was used to compile the Webots controller library.

Comment: Thank You for your advice. I actually did it myself. It's just version 4.30 is a little bit different from the 2.x versions. This version has only two static library but because I did according to 2.x version It just didn't work. Right now it can compile and link.